# Ubuntu linux: why "ar" command shows weird date/time information of archive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, time, archive

I'm using ubuntu linux 16.04, just created a "a.c" file, I used

```
gcc -c a.c
```

to get a.o, and

```
ar rc liba.a a.o
```

to generate archive.

But when I use ar command to see its information, I got weird date information:

```
$ ar tv liba.a
rw-r--r-- 0/0   1408 Jan  1 08:00 1970 a.o
```

The date is not Jan 1st, the time is not 08:00
Why I get this information?

Thanks.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 ar (GNU Binutils 2.24) show the right date time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By default the [linux] ar command creates deterministic archives which do not contain time stamps."

If you want to include timestamps, use the U modifier:

```
ar tvU libra.a
```

Comment: Yes, "ar rcU liba.a a.o" to generate, and then ar tv liba.a will show correct time stamp of the "a.o" file contained inside archive files.